# XPath: How to check multiple attributes across similar nodes

Tags: xpath, attributes, match

If I have some xml like:

```
    <root>
   <customers>
        <customer firstname="Joe" lastname="Bloggs" description="Member of the Bloggs family"/>
        <customer firstname="Joe" lastname="Soap" description="Member of the Soap family"/>
        <customer firstname="Fred" lastname="Bloggs" description="Member of the Bloggs family"/>
        <customer firstname="Jane" lastname="Bloggs" description="Is a member of the Bloggs family"/>
   </customers>
 </root>
```

How do I get, in pure XPath - not XSLT - an xpath expression that detects rows where lastname is the same, but has a different description? So it would pull the last node above?

Comment: You need to define output requirements in a more formal way. Say, there are 4 nodes with the same lastname, but 2 of them share description X, and 2 other share a different description Y. Which should be in the output? Also, what happens if input has nodes with different lastnames? What if a particular group of nodes (defined by lastname) only contains one node - output it, or not?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes. :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get, in pure XPath - not XSLT
>   - an xpath expression that detects rows where lastname is the same, but
>   has a different description?

**Here's how to do this with a single XPath expression**:

```
   "/*/*/customer
        [@lastname='Bloggs'
       and
        not(@description
           = preceding-sibling::*[@lastname='Bloggs']/@description
            )
        ]"
```

This expression selects all `<customer>` elements with attribute `lastname` equal to "Bloggs" and different value of the attribute `description`.

The selected nodes are:

```
<customer firstname="Joe" lastname="Bloggs" description="Member of the Bloggs family"/>
<customer firstname="Jane" lastname="Bloggs" description="Is a member of the Bloggs family"/>
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do this for all lastnames at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
/root/customers/customer[@lastname='Bloggs'
  and not(@description = preceding-sibling::*[@lastname='Bloggs']/@description)
  and not(@description = following-sibling::*[@lastname='Bloggs']/@description)]
```

It would perform better doing it in steps, though.